# Encrypting and Externalization the password present in wso2 API manager in cloud (Openshift )

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, wso2-api-manager, wso2

How to use the secret yaml  for encrypting the passwords present in the WSO2-API in openshift or kubernetes?Whether can we expose the encrypted password present in cipher-text.properties file or is there any other configuration needs to be done while deploying on cloud?

I able to find the solution for encrypting the password for on premise in below link but not able to get any information for exposing and encrypting the password details for cloud. Can you please provide some direction where can I get this information or how to do this configuration.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Working+with+Encrypted+Passwords